# What does CodePen.io does to support CSS3 animations in IE9-?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I wrote a PacMan with pure CSS3, and put it on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/telud/2/). If you visit this bin in modern browser, you will see a blue pacman. But if you use IE9 or even older version of IE, the animation won't work. Also, Google told me that IE9 is the last version of IE that doesn't support pure CSS3 animations.

But then I put the same code on [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/tjwudi/pen/kfDLy), and I visit using IE9, the animation works! Then I tried to visit the page in IE8 and IE7 (via BrowseEmAll, a tool for debugging cross browser compatibility), it worked, again!

Surely, CodePen.io cannot automatically provide some JavaScript fallback for my animation. So how does it make my animation work under IE9-?

Comment: They have to use a js fallback given it's impossible with CSS in IE9

Comment: I tried this in a VM on IE8, and it didn't work on codepen.io.

Comment: You can just change the compatibility mode from the dev tools to see if the animation works in IE. You don't need BrowseEmAll for that. Animations were not supported till IE10, when the spec reached a stable state, http://caniuse.com/#search=key. For IE9- you would need a polyfil to make them work.